# design effect using jQuery

Tags: jquery, transition

Please take a look at this link:

http://melissahie.com/

When you click on any of the links on this website, you will see a pretty good transition of the page.  I am assuming this effect can be achieved through jQuery.  Any guidance is appreciated?

Pratik

Comment: She is actually using MooTools and not jQuery.  The code for the transitions are pretty well laid out @ http://melissahie.com/js/mymootools.js

Answer (score 2):

That "effect" is achieved by placing fixed size absolute-positioned divs on a page and use Javascript to scroll the document.

If the scrollbars were turned on, you would just scroll and be able to see all the pages.  With the body set to *overflow: hidden* you can use JavaScript to scroll the page.  All you need is a "smooth scrolling" plugin.

Edit: Also, it looks like crap on a high resolution.

Answer (score 0):

[`$.scrollTo`](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) is what you're after I bet. (And [demo page](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/))

*Just my $0.02, don't duplicate that. An absolutely-positively-fixed-sized-site. Ew. It's basally a website designed as a canvas with scrolling using to go between the "pages".*